# How to pass parameter to EditOptions DataURL method for edittype="select" for inline editing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I need to get different set of values in a dropdown column in jqGrid. I am using **jqGrid 4.4.4**

There are two parts of the problem

1. **How to pass a parameter to my DataURL method?**

The column model

```
{ key: false, name: 'ContactName', index: 'ContactName', editable: true, width: '100px', sortable: false, frozen: true, formatter: 'select',  edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: {

                        dataUrl: '/InvestorList/GetContactList'
                    }
```

And 2. **How to populate the value in the cell when it is not in Editing mode?** I am using inline editing.

Thanks,

Comment: **Which fork of jqGrid (free jqGrid, Guriddo jqGrid JS or old jqGrid in version <= 4.7) you use and in which version?**. If you have two separated questions you should post separated questions on the stackoverflow too. It simplify indexing of questions by searching engine and make finding of questions/answer easy for other peoples. The part "the value selected in the row" is absolutely unclear.  It's unclear what you mean, because the cell can be selected only in cell editing mode, but you write about inline editing.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg I have edited the post. It it clear to understand now? I kept both together because their basically part of the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you use so old version than you have restricted possibilities, but I looks in the code of jqGrid 4.4.4. It have already one feature which you can use: you can use `postData` defined as function:

```js
{ name: 'ContactName', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: false, frozen: true,
    formatter: 'select',  edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        dataUrl: '/InvestorList/GetContactList',
        postData: function (rowid, value, cmName) {
            return {
                myId: rowid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I removed in the definition of `ContactName` unneeded `index` property and fixed the value of `width` property from wrong value `'100px'` to `100`. The value should be a number.

The above code add `myId` parameter with rowid to the request to `'/InvestorList/GetContactList'`.

To set the value of the cell, if the row is not in the inline/cell editing mode, you can use just [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method.

Comment: It's still not working unfortunately.

I have this Controller method:
`public JsonResult GetContactList(string projectId)
        {
            var contacts = context.GetContactList(projectId);
            return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`

Comment: @Imran: What is "not working"? Do you used Fiddler or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to trace HTTP traffic? Which data (parameters of `InvestorList/GetContactList`) will be send to the server? Which JavaScript code you use now? You should replace `myId` to `projectId`. Do you prevent caching of the previous Ajax request? One can use `context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate); context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge (new TimeSpan (0));` to set `"Cache-Control: private, max-age=0"` HTTP headers of the HTTP response.

Comment: I tried to debug but it doesn't even run the function for `postData:` I have run it after clearing the cache, but same result. The parameter is renamed to `projectId` as well. The controller methods `projectId` parameter is null. In Network traffic, it has `X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Imran: **Which JavaScript code you use now?** Are you sure that you use jqGrid 4.4.4? You can set breakpoint in [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L343) of  `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and see how your `postData` callback defined in `editoptions` will be called with the corresponding parameters. I recommend you to set cache behavior on the server side by `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge (new TimeSpan (0));`

Comment: @Imran: One can use `[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]` attribute of controller action alternatively.

Comment: This is what the file looks like: http://screencast.com/t/86tC9P4fOc. It's gotta be 4.4.4. I have a minified version, Should I replace it with actual source files? Does it require a specific sequence for adding in the project? It has this comment:
`Modules: grid.base.js; jquery.fmatter.js; grid.custom.js; grid.common.js; grid.formedit.js; grid.filter.js; grid.inlinedit.js; grid.celledit.js; jqModal.js; jqDnR.js; grid.subgrid.js; grid.grouping.js; grid.treegrid.js; grid.import.js; JsonXml.js; grid.tbltogrid.js; grid.jqueryui.js; `

Comment: @Imran: You should always use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` during the whole development process. All demos which I post on the stackoverflow contains only `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` (with exception of demos which shows some performance effects).

Comment: I downloaded version 4.8.2 from Github. In the `jqGrid-master\js` folder, there's the file called `jquery.jqGrid.js` But none with `src.js`. I'm thinking it might be a quicker to upgrade the jqgrid instead of debugging the original code. Any thoughts about that @Oleg

Comment: There are two forks of jqGrid now: 1) from Tony: [Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.8.2](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) which you downloaded, it has `jquery.jqGrid.js` as min-minimized file 2) from my: [free jqGrid 4.9](https://github.com/orgs/free-jqgrid/dashboard). You can download it or use directly from CDN (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). It has `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` as non-minimized file. My fork is for free and I can fix any bug or implement new features myself. See readme and wiki for description of new features.

Comment: @Imran: In both forks you can use `dataUrl` defined **as callback function**. See [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.0/js/grid.common.js#L441) for example.

Comment: Many thanks @Oleg, the parameter is now passing when I used v 4.9.0. I got another problem now in populating the dropdown in the column. I have made a separate post here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999728/jquery-unrecognized-expression-error-in-jqgrid-dataurl-method-for-edittype-sele)