# jQuery unrecognized Expression error in jqGrid dataUrl method for edittype='select'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

This is in continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981085/how-to-pass-parameter-to-editoptions-dataurl-method-for-edittype-select-for-in/30981678?noredirect=1#comment50022434_30981678) thread. I'm using the **free-jqGrid 4.9.0** and have inline editing.

```
 { name: 'ContactName',  editable: true, width: 100, sortable: false, frozen: true, formatter: 'select',  edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: {
                        dataUrl: '/InvestorList/GetContactList',
                        postData: function (rowid, value, cmName) {

                            return { projectId: rowid };
                        }
                    }
```

In my ASP .NET MVC **controller**, I have the following method:

```
public JsonResult GetContactList(string projectId)
    {
        var contacts = new Dictionary<string, string>();//context.GetContactList(projectId);
        contacts.Add("123","IAM1");
        contacts.Add("1234", "IAM2");
        contacts.Add("12345", "IAM3");
        return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Using IE developer tools, this is the response:

```
{"123":"IAM1","1234":"IAM2","12345":"IAM3"}
```

But I get the following error,

> Unhandled exception at line 2, column 12461 in http://localhost:51176/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js 
>        0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"123":"IAM1","1234":"IAM2","12345":"IAM3"}

I'm wondering what kind of format does `dataUrl` expect because I use the exact same format for other columns e.g. `editoptions: { value: TeaserStatusList }` In this case `TeaserStatusList` has the same format as `{"123":"IAM1","1234":"IAM2","12345":"IAM3"}`

Thanks

Update:

```
{ name: 'ContactId', editable: true, width: 100, sortable: false, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {  dataUrl: '/InvestorList/GetContactList',
                        postData: function (rowid, value, cmName) {                            
                            var accid = $(gridId).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "AccountId");
                            return { accountId: accid };
                        },
                        buildSelect: function (data) {
                            var s = "<select>";
                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                                s += '<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>';
                            });
                            return s + "</select>";
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid expect that `dataUrl` returns HTML fragment with `<select>` statement. Thus you should add `buildSelect` property in `editoptions` which converts the server response to the string with `<select>` statement. The corresponding code could be something like below

```
buildSelect: function (data) {
     var s = "<select>", i, l, val;
     if (data != null) {
         for (val in data) {
             if (data.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
                 s += "<option value='" + val + "'>" + data[val] + "</option>";
             }
         }
     }
     return s + "</select>";
 }
```

I didn't tested the code, but it seems to me it corresponds the format of data returned from `GetContactList` action.

I would recommend you to add the line `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge (new TimeSpan(0));` at the begining of the action `GetContactList` to be sure that you will have no problem with caching and the action `GetContactList` will be called every time.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, there is a problem still. the field shows the value and not the text for the field. I have `ContactId` and `ContactName` used for the dropdown. In this case, dropdown works fine, but once edit is done, there is no text in the cell. How to get around that problem?

Comment: @Imran: I see that you use `formatter: 'select'`. It's very strange. What format have **input data for initial filling the grid** (not for editing)? The problem is easy: `formatter: 'select'` will be used during filling the grid already. It expects **`editoptions.value`** and can't be used with `dataUrl`. Moreover the input data for the column `ContactName` have to contains **values** like `"123"` or `"1234"` and not texts like `"IAM1"` or `"IAM2"`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select).

Comment: So I removed `formatter: 'select' ` and added ContactId as the field name. It now shows the values like ` "123" ` and so on when the grid is loaded. The dropdown with values is visible when the row is clicked. Am I missing something?

Comment: :I have added my colmodel in the question

Comment: @Imran: Which data you use as the input for `ContactName` column (during filling the data in the grid) now? Is it texts like "IAM1" or "IAM2"? If you don't use ids (values) like "123" or "1234" then why you should create `<select>` with different values and texts? Is it not better that `'/InvestorList/GetContactList'` returns `["IAM1", "IAM2", "IAM3"]` instead of `{"123":"IAM1","1234":"IAM2","12345":"IAM3"}`? If it's what you need then you should change `buildSelect` to process the new format of data.

Comment: no that returns the same set of values. The trouble is that how to show the current selected value in the cell after the user updates the contact using the dropdown

Comment: @Imran: It seems to me that you misunderstand a little the problem. The value will be saved in the same format like during filling, but initial filling can display even wrong formatted input data. You should really solve the problem of filling and editing at once. If you use `formatter: 'select'` or not use you have different format of input data and you need create different format of `<option>` in `ContactName` column. If you *don't use `formatter: 'select'*  then `value` and text of all options have to be the same (you can't use `"1234"` value and need use `"IAM2"` instead).

Comment: so if I understand correctly, in this case where I am not using `formatter: 'select' `, the value and text have to be the same. And we cannot have key/value pairs in the `<select> ` list?

Comment: @Imran: Yes, it's so.

Comment: oh this is sad, I have to change the design in that case. Would you consider it to be a good feature to develop in the future?

Comment: @Imran: I'm ready to implement new features, but I'm still not sure there it's a problem at all. What you suggest to implement? If jqGrid hold internally only the texts like `"IAM1"` and `"IAM2"` than it's unclear for me why one should saves values like `"1234"` instead of "IAM2"? I'm ready to implement a feature if you demonstrate me that it's common problem of editing.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this other than manually creating the selects.

Comment: @Amete: I'm not sure what you mean. Is the question about alternative implementation? Is it some suggestion to change the code of free jqGrid?  One can't just change the semantic of the existing option. The callback `dataUrl` required that the server returns HTML fragment with `<select>`. The interface exist since many many versions of jqGrid. One could introduce *extension* of the existing functionality **without breakinh the old one**.

Comment: @Amete: The problem is that JSON response could be good `["option1", "option2"]` or `[{"value":"op1", "text":"option1"}, "value":"op2", "text":"option2"}]` in other cased. One can use `context-type` HTTP header of the response to detect HTML/JSON response, but some servers not set `context-type` correctly and use for example `plain/text`. What should be done in the case. It you would suggest good new options which don't break existing functionality and extend it for JSON and still with enough flexibility then I would implement it.

Comment: I was thinking just updating the dataUrl to get Json from the server and avoid doing the buildSelect. But As you explained there is not easy way.